# Mariadb sharding?

Tags: mariadb, sharding

I'm trying to implement a mariadb sharding for learning purpose. I have looked into database sharding in general and found mariadb spider storage engine support sharding. I do not want spider storage engine and like to test tokudb storage engine due to it's high performance. I plan to shard a simple database over two separate VM instances. My questions are,

1. Can someone point me good tutorial or book to archive this ?
2. PostgreSQL support connection pooling and load balancing tools ( ex: pg-pool) . Does mariadb has tools like this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to both of your question could be [MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/maxscale). MariaDB MaxScale is a database proxy which supports connection pooling, load balancing, automatic failover, query routing, read-write splitting and more. The query routing feature is used to achieve sharding. For a tutorial, try e.g. [this one](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-14/maxscale-simple-sharding-with-two-servers/).

An alternative solution could be [ProxySQL](http://www.proxysql.com/), which is a competing database proxy product with some of the same features, including [sharding](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/08/30/mysql-sharding-with-proxysql/). One advantage of ProxySQL over MaxScale is the license GPLv3 vs [BSL](https://mariadb.com/bsl-faq-adopting#whatis), although BSL software becomes GPL after a certain amount of time. MaxScale 2.1 [became GPL](https://mariadb.com/projects-using-bsl-11/) on 1. July 2019.